# Pass PDO Database object from include script to class

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I'm having an issue passing a database object to a class.  I receive the following error when running index.php:

"**Warning**: Missing argument 1 for Client::__construct(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\mobile_dispatch\index.php on line 14 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\mobile_dispatch\classes\class.client.inc on line 25

**Notice**: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\mobile_dispatch\classes\class.client.inc on line 26

**Fatal error**: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\mobile_dispatch\classes\class.client.inc on line 32"

I am not sure how to pass the $db object from mysql_login_pdo.php to the Client class.  Thanks for any assistance.

Here is the offending code:

index.php

```
<?php 
require_once './classes/class.client.inc'; 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Mobile Dispatch</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        echo 'Hello World!  The database connected just fine ;)';

        $client = new Client;
        $client->add_to_db();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

class.client.inc

```
<?php

require './classes/mysql_login_pdo.php';

class Client {

    public $firstName;
    public $middleName;
    public $lastName;
    public $streetAddress1;
    public $streetAddress2;
    public $city;
    public $state;
    public $zip;
    public $phone_home;
    public $phone_cell;
    public $phone_office;
    protected $db;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function add_to_db() {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `clients` "
                . "VALUES (:id, :firstName, :middleName, :lastName)";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':id' => null,
            ':firstName' => 'Mary',
            ':middleName' => 'G',
            ':lastName' => 'Smith'
        ));
    }
}
```

mysql_login_pdo.php

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; //Host Name
$port = '3306'; //Default MySQL Port
$dbname = "mobile_dispatch"; //Database Name
$db_username = "user"; //MySQL Username
$db_password = "password"; //MySQL Password

//Data Source Name = Mysql
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname";

//Try to connect to the database and return the $db connection info.  if not,
//stop processing all scripts and return a generalised message
try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password); //Connect to DB
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERR_NONE);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); //Creates TRUE prepared statements
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die("Cannot connect to database");
}
```

EDIT:
Updated index.php:

```
<?php 
require_once './classes/mysql_login_pdo.php';
require_once './classes/class.client.inc'; 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Mobile Dispatch</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        echo 'Hello World!  The database connected just fine ;)';

        $client = new Client($db);
        $client->add_to_db();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

This results in the following error:
**Fatal error**: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\mobile_dispatch\classes\class.client.inc on line 31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass the $db-parameter in the constructur:

```
$client = new Client($db);
```

Comment: I passed in the $db object to the constructor, as you've said to.  I also removed the require from class.Client.inc and added it to index.php.  I am now getting the following error: **Fatal error**: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\mobile_dispatch\classes\class.client.inc on line 31.  Any ideas?

Comment: No, in your index.php you wrote  $client = new Client; which is wrong. You must replace this line with $client=new Client($db); .
You declared the constructor with one parameter, but you called it without one. Also, you have to add parenthesis if you don't have parameters, too.

Comment: I ended up doing that.  I just didn't update the code ;)  I will update the post with the new code.

Comment: Ok, please show us the result of print_r($stmt); after $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);

Comment: It returns an empty value

Comment: Ok, does echo ($stmt===FALSE); at the same position output 1?

Comment: Hm, then there's a problem with your statement. (If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns FALSE => [link](http://de2.php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepare.php) ). Does the table exist and has exactly the given 4 columns in the used order?

Comment: So.... I completely forgot about this requirement.  That is what the problem was.  I did not insert a value into every column.  As embarrassing as it is, I'll leave the post here for anyone who comes across it in the future.  Thanks @micwag ;)